# UIImage looses its orientation while converting it into CIImage, then into CGImage and back to UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, cgimage, ciimage

I know there are tons of questions like this but their solutions don't work for me.

**NOTE:** The image is downloaded from the Internet. It isn't taken from `iPhone`'s camera.

I have a `UIImage`. To do some image processing operations I use `Metal` and present the image in a `MTKView`. So, I convert the image into a `CIImage`. 
 After doing all the modifications to the image I convert it back into `CGImage` and then into `UIImage` and save it.

As a result the saved image's orientation is wrong.

I'm not sure in which step it looses its orientation (when converting from `UIImage` into `CIImage` for adding to `MTKView`, or while converting from `CIImage` into `CGImage` and then into `UIImage` to save it). Because I'm not sure, bellow I provide everything I've tried for each steps:

For converting from `UIImage` into `CIImage`:

Initially I was simply converting the image in this way:

```
let let ciImage = CIImage(image: image)
```

Then I tried to use the following way:

```
  let ciImage = CIImage(image: image)?.oriented(forExifOrientation: imageOrientationToTiffOrientation(value: image.imageOrientation))
```

Here is the method `imageOrientationToTiffOrientation`'s implementation (I found it [here](https://github.com/FlexMonkey/CIImage-UIImage-Orientation-Fix)):

```
func imageOrientationToTiffOrientation(value: UIImageOrientation) -> Int32
{
    switch (value)
    {
    case .up:
        return 1
    case .down:
        return 3
    case .left:
        return 8
    case .right:
        return 6
    case .upMirrored:
        return 2
    case .downMirrored:
        return 4
    case .leftMirrored:
        return 5
    case .rightMirrored:
        return 7
    }
}
```

For converting from `CIImage` into `CGImage` and then into `UIImage`:

I convert `CIImage` into `CGImage` as usual:

```
let cgImage = context?.createCGImage(ciImage, from: ciImage.extent)
```

Then I convert `cgImage` into `UIImage` (`imageToSave`) this way:

```
let imageToSave = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage, scale: image.scale, orientation: imageOrientation)
```

`imageOrientation` and `image.scale` are the original image's orientation and scale.

As a result, the saved image still has a wrong orientatio.

Interestingly when I print those images orientations raw values, they are the same `0` which is the `.up`, however as I said, after saving, the orientation is wrong.

I'm quite confused why is this happening. If you have any suggestions about how to fix this, I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Please show your actual code and explain how you “know” you’ve lost your orientation. There is no such thing as “saving” a UIImage so it is unclear what you are doing. All you can save is image data. If your goal is to save the image data from a CIImage, you should be calling `CIContext().writeJPEGRepresentation`.

Answer (score 5):

**TLDR:**

```
let uiImage: UIImage = ...
let ciImage = CIImage(image: uiImage, options:
    [.applyOrientationProperty: true,
     .properties: [kCGImagePropertyOrientation: CGImagePropertyOrientation(uiImage.imageOrientation).rawValue]])
```

To convert `UIImageOrientation` to `CGImagePropertyOrientation` this code uses extension from https://developer.apple.com/documentation/imageio/cgimagepropertyorientation

```
extension CGImagePropertyOrientation {
    init(_ uiOrientation: UIImageOrientation) {
        switch uiOrientation {
            case .up: self = .up
            case .upMirrored: self = .upMirrored
            case .down: self = .down
            case .downMirrored: self = .downMirrored
            case .left: self = .left
            case .leftMirrored: self = .leftMirrored
            case .right: self = .right
            case .rightMirrored: self = .rightMirrored
        }
    }
}
```

**Long version:**

I just had similar issue. When converting UIImage to CIImage, the image may occur in wrong orientation:

```
let uiImage: UIImage = ...
let ciImage CIImage(image: uiImage) /* does not use uiImage orientation */
```

The simplest solution was to use `oriented(_:)` method to change orientation:

```
let ciImage = CIImage(image: uiImage)?.oriented(CGImagePropertyOrientation(uiImage.imageOrientation))
/* uses CGImagePropertyOrientation extension (see above) */
```

This could be ok, but `oriented(_:)` method creates a new image. I thought there must be a way to create properly oriented `CIImage` without intermediate object. And there is! Though I didn't find it anywhere on Internet, and it is not documented clearly enough by Apple, so I post it here. @matt made a step in right direction, but it wasn't enough.

The solution was "encrypted" in `applyOrientationProperty` description.

> Images can contain metadata that reveals the orientation at capture time. **You can load
> this metadata into CIImage** with imageWithContentsOfURL: or init(data:)
> when the captured image contains orientation metadata. Use any of the
> initWith:options: methods if the **properties (NSDictionary of metadata
> properties) option is also provided**.

Important parts are emphasized. That was a key.
It was also important to not confuse `options` and `properties` here. )

Answer (score 3):

The way to pick up the orientation from the original UIImage when creating a CIImage is to say:

```
let ciImage = CIImage(image: image, options: [.applyOrientationProperty:true])!
```

When you're done with the CIImage, save the data to disk with `CIContext().writeJPEGRepresentation` and the orientation metadata will be maintained.

Comment: Tried but did not work. I already have a CIIMage made from CMSampleBuffer. I want to place another image(kinda sticker) on it so used the composited(over:) method from CIImage. But the orientation is not right for the sticker.

Comment: @nr5 I would suggest that you should ask about that formally as a new question. Maybe someone can help.

Comment: I tried: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55574172/avcapturevideopreviewlayer-add-overlays-and-capture-photo-in-ios

Comment: @nr5 Nothing there about orientation as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method

```
 func image(with image: UIImage?, scaledToSizeKeepingAspect newSize: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
    var newSize = newSize
    var imgHeight = Float(image?.size.height ?? 0.0)
    var imgWeight = Float(image?.size.width ?? 0.0)
    var fact: Float = 0.0
    if imgHeight > imgWeight {
        fact = Float(CGFloat(imgHeight) / newSize.width)
    } else {
        fact = Float(CGFloat(imgWeight) / newSize.height)
    }
    imgHeight = imgHeight / fact
    imgWeight = imgWeight / fact
    newSize = CGSize(width: CGFloat(imgWeight), height: CGFloat(imgHeight))
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize)
    // Tell the old image to draw in this new context, with the desired
    // new size
    image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height))
        // Get the new image from the context
    let newImage: UIImage? = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    // End the context
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    // Return the new image.
    return newImage
}
```

Call method like this :

image(withImage: image, scaledToSizeKeepingAspect: image.size)

here image is UIImage object which image you want to change pass in this method.