# AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer add overlays and capture photo in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, metal, core-image

The initial idea was to start a camera stream via `AVCaptureSession`, find faces in that raw `CMSampleBuffer` and then add some images as layers on `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` and then take a screenshot.

After completing that, found out later that the `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext` won't work with `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`, so taking screenshot would not solve my purpose here.

So I used `Metal` and `MTKView` instead to perform some live rendering and the results are good with the combination of CoreImage Filters and Metal. I already know how to detect faces and alter that part of the face using inbuilt CoreImage filters but I can't find a suitable method to add an image on to another image.

How can I blend two images with respect to positioning in the background image? I have CIImage to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load your overlay into a `CIImage`, then use `transformed(by matrix: CGAffineTransform)` to move it to the face position, and finally use `composited(over dest: CIImage)` to blend it over the `CIImage` from the video buffer. 
You probably have to put in some work to transfer between the different coordinate spaces.

There are also a lot of more complex compositing filters available. Check out the [filters](https://cifilter.io/) in the `CICategoryCompositeOperation` category.

Comment: Will try this. I am still not sure If I am using the best approach for, "writing to a video in real time". From what I've read, Metal replaced OpenGL. In my example I took the apple's example code (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/avcamfilter_applying_filters_to_a_capture_stream?language=objc) for metal and then added CIDetector to it for face specific editing. I have seen Apple's SquareCam example (https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/SquareCam/Introduction/Intro.html) where we click a photo but the editing is not in real time

Comment: Adding to my above comment, the squarecam example adds the image as a layer to AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer and when you take a picture, it again finds the face in that picture and then draws on it. So the detection is twice which feels incorrect

Comment: While converting UIImage to CIImage, the orientation is lost. It seems width is converted into height. I think I need to add the metadata from UIIMage while making CIImage CIImage.init(image: options:), using the https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/ciimageoption/1437679-properties